# "The name 'y_pred:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'y_pred', does not exist in the graph."

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've defined y_pred, still, it's giving this error. Any kind of help will be good.

```
with graph.as_default():

# Input data 
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels),name 
= 'x_train')
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder( 
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels),name="y_train")
tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

........

train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits,name"y_pred")
#print(train_prediction.shape)
valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))
```

In Prediction step:

```
  ...
  y_pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_pred:0")
  ...



KeyError: "The name 'y_pred:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The 
operation, 'y_pred', does not exist in the graph."
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is only a copy+paste error, but

```
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits,name"y_pred")
```

is missing an equal sign from `name="y_pred"`. It should be

```
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax( logits, name = "y_pred" )
```